# mod-rewrite, htaccess and pass through

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess problem which is slowly destroying my sanity. In my project, I have a root folder with a 404.php in it, and an explicit subdirectory called **signup**. The subdirectory contains a file called **index.php** which performs processing. The project is using XAMPP under Windows 7.

The root .htaccess file contains the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

The .htaccess in the **signup** physical subdirectory contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/signup/page1$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) signup/index.php?page=1 [NC,L]
```

The rewrite log below seems to be deciding that */signup/page1* does not exist before the rewrite module can even check it. Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

```
10.1.1.201 - - [03/Dec/2012:15:06:58 +1100] [testsite.com/sid#463bd0][rid#4412b10/initial] (1) [perdir C:/workspace/project/public/signup/] pass through C:/workspace/project/public/signup/page1
10.1.1.201 - - [03/Dec/2012:15:06:58 +1100] [testsite.com/sid#463bd0][rid#4500fc0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/workspace/project/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/workspace/project/public/404.php -> 404.php
10.1.1.201 - - [03/Dec/2012:15:06:58 +1100] [testsite.com/sid#463bd0][rid#4500fc0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/workspace/project/public/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri '404.php'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `RewriteBase` like this in the `.htaccess` inside your `signup` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteBase /signup

RewriteRule ^page1$ /signup/index.php?page=1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Oddly strange, I'd swear I tried this and it didn't work. Oh well, it's working now, anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^signup/page1/?$  http://mydomain.com/signup/index.php?page=1 [L]
```

Comment: This change does not alter the behaviour or the logging output in any way. I have tried it both in the root .htaccess and the subdirectory.